# Multiple values for same parameter in GET request?

Tags: apex, rest-api

How can i get multiple values for same parameter for below rest request using Rest request method?

`https://cs40.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Membership?include=Membership:member&_include=Membership:organization&_include=Membership:service`

Comment: It looks like there's no defined standard, it varies by implementation, see [Correct way to pass multiple values for same parameter name in GET request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059773/correct-way-to-pass-multiple-values-for-same-parameter-name-in-get-request)

Comment: You might also want to read [(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/), an article I found recently. Formatting your URL like this is *asking* for problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to end up parsing the query string "manually," because the OOTB method will only keep one of the values. For example, RestRequest.params is a `Map<String, String>`, so only one value is kept. Ditto for using PageReference. Your best choice would basically be to start with a Url, then pull out the query string, then parse the remaining string.

```
String queryString = new Url(RestContext.request.requestURI).getQuery();
if(queryString != null) {
    String[] queryParams = queryString.split('&');
    for(String queryParam: queryParams) {
        String[] keyPair = queryParam.split('=',2);
        // Do something with keyPair[0] and keyPair[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an error :"System.StringException: no protocol: /Membership"